# Marcus number fields exercise 30 chapter 3

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

This exercise wants me to prove that for each $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ there are infinitely many primes $p \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$. It seems that this can be based on the fact that $f$ has a root mod $p$ for infinitely many primes $p$ whenever $f$ is a nonconstant polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}$. This is from the exercise 30 on chapter 3 of Marcus' *Number Fields*. Please help me.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83996/problems-on-cyclotomic-polynomials

Comment: Thank you @Gerry Myerson. This can be solved by using (d)(vi).

Comment: So you won't mind if your question is closed as a duplicate of that earlier one?

Comment: OK, I don't mind.